# How can I configure my audio ports on MX-Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, audio, mx-linux

A while ago my PC 3.5mm headphone jack broke, but I was able to fix that problem using the Windows setting to switch the tasks of headphone and microphone jack. Basically I switched them, so my Microphone goes into the headphone jack and my headphone jack goes into the microphone jack. It worked perfectly, but recently, I switched to Linux.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do that again? How can I make the operative system switch the ports so my headphone jack is that for the microphone and the microphone one is the one for the headphones?